# Unable to place breakpoint in Chrome Devtools for my Vue application

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-devtools

I am unable to place any breakpoints in my Vue components (All the line numbers are greyed). This was working fine until a recent update to Chrome (Updated to version 102.0.5005.63 from 86.0.4240.75). What could be the issue here? I am using Webpack to bundle.

[Screenshot of Chrome Devtools - v102](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27mZm.png)

[Screenshot of Chrome Devtools- v86](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZOFN.png)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . What Chrome version? Did you try to use a different version at the same time? "What could be the issue here?" - a bug in Chrome, obviously, if your observations are correct

Comment: The current version is 102.0.5005.63.
I have tested in version 86.0.4240.75 and it works fine.

Updated main post with the screenshot.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in devtools.

Comment: Having the same problem and it's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

Version 103.0.5060.114 (Official Build) (64-bit)
same here in the latest version